# Prevent scroll bar from overlapping custom task pane

Tags: c#, winforms, scrollbar

I have made a custom task pane in Windows Forms. My task pane contains a panel which contains number of `pictureBox`'s vertically down the task pane. It looks fine on my screen until I make my screen smaller and the vertical scroll bar appears, which then overlaps my `pictureBox`'s. I have tried a number of things such as margin, padding, putting my panel inside another panel an and changing the outer panel to `AutoScroll`. None of these have made a difference. Is there a way of making my task pane move to the left by the width of the scroll bar?

As you can see from the image below the scroll bar is overlapping my image

[image]

Where as I want it to show up like this

[image]

Comment: I think you'll need to deal with the width of the `Panel`, making it wide enough to accommodate the width of the images plus the scrollbar (`SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth`).  Either at the outset, or once you've detected the scrollbar's appearance.

Comment: Second screenshot doesn't contain scrollbar. Do you simply want to hide it? Which container exactly contains `pictureBox`'es (may or may not matter, `AutoScroll = false` should normally hide scrollbars)? In any case consider to add [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you want to get an answer.

Comment: @Sinatr I don't want to hide it I just was showing what it looked like before and after I changed the screen size. I want to be able to see the full image whenever the scroll bar appears

Comment: @DonBoitnott I don't want to change the size of the panel because then the images won't be centred on my task pane if the scrollbar does/doesn't appear depending on the users screen size.

Comment: @LarsTech I have a scroll bar when the screen is too small for the content and I don't have one if all the content can fit on the screen. I don't have a problem getting a scroll bar my problem lies when the scroll bar appears it overlaps the content of my task bar such as the images as can be seen from the pictures I uploaded.